# Piping subversion revision numbers to diff

Tags: svn, shell, command-line, cygwin

OK, so I can run a command like this to get a list of revision numbers made on a certain date or date range:

```
svn log -q -r{2012-01-25}:HEAD | grep '^r[0-9]' | cut -d\| -f1 | cut -b2-
```

This works fine and gives me a list like this

```
12345
12346
12347
```

Now, I would like to pass these revision numbers to the diff command, so running a simple svn diff on a revision number manually works as expected i.e.

```
svn diff -c12345
```

But, if I attempt to pipe the revision list to the diff command like this

```
svn log -q -r{2012-01-25}:HEAD | grep '^r[0-9]' | cut -d\| -f1 | cut -b2- | xargs svn diff -c
```

it returns an error that the node was not found - looks to me like I am passing the arguments wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, in the last part of the pipe, `xargs` is trying to execute:

```
svn diff -c 12345 12346 12347
```

when it should try:

```
svn diff -c 12345
svn diff -c 12346
svn diff -c 12347
```

because the `-c` option only accepts one argument.

To fix that, try to replace `xargs` with `xargs -n1`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each of `12345`, `12346`, `12347` is passed as a separate argument; you need it to be joined with the `-c` into a single argument.

Assuming you're using the GNU findutils version of `xargs`, you can use the `-I` option.  An example not using svn:

```
$ printf "12345\n12346\n12347\n" | xargs -n 1 -I{} echo svn diff -c{}
svn diff -c12345
svn diff -c12346
svn diff -c12347
```

Note that this invokes `svn diff` once for each version number.  Your command invokes `svn` once with multiple version numbers.  If you want to invoke svn once for multiple version numbers:

```
svn diff -c12345 12346 12347
```

then a different solution will be necessary.

**EDIT :**

Reading the other answer and the svn documentation, it looks like you can have a space after `-c`, so either `svn diff -c12345` or `svn diff -c 12345` is valid.  In that case, just using `-n 1` should do the trick.